# How to show months in wordpress archive page?

Tags: archives

I am a newbie to wordpress and have no knowledge of PHP.

I want to show the months in my archive page, in this manner

[image]

where, it shows the starting month when i my first post was made and continues to shows all months and year, till the current month of the year.

I want the months to be hyperlinks of this manner `http://bibhudutta.com/2014/3/` based on each month and year.

Please help me out, how to do it in PHP and wordpress.

Comment: This is not a place where you should post a wish-list and expect someone to do your work for you. [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Thanks for your advice. Its not that I am new to this community, i am well aware of forum rules, being a member in SO. All I needed was a small help. Anways Thanks :)

Comment: Well aware of the rules but willfully disregarded them, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this,

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12 ) ); ?>
```

Refer to [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives) for further customisation,